# Angular ng-model in appended Html code not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

This is my code. Where I dynamically add html on a button click.but the ng-model which I gave there is not working.

Can anyone solve my issue

```
$scope.addParam = function(selected) {
  if (selected == "bucket_policy_privacy_status") {
    var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#inputParameters'));
    myElement.append('<input type="text" style="width:220px" class="form-control" name="" disabled="" value=' + selected + '> <select class="form-control" style="width:196px" ng-model="fields.privacyStatus" ><option value="range">Range</option><option value="public">Public</option><option value="private">Private</option></select> <br><br>');
      $scope.$watch('fields.privacyStatus', function() {
        var privacy_status = $scope.fields.privacyStatus;
        alert();
        var status = {
          "term": {}
        }
        status.term[selected] = privacy_status;
        output.push(status);
      });
    $('#params option[value="bucket_policy_privacy_status"]').remove();
    $scope.input.select = "bucket_owner";
  }
};
```

Comment: It is not the *Angular way* to do this...

Comment: you have messed the code, what is your expectation!

Comment: Can you suggest a way to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you will need to change:

You need to use Angulars `$compile` option to evaluate angular attributes/expressions when inserting HTML dynamically.

Adding the line below after you added the element ot the DOM should do the trick:

`$compile(angular.element('.form-control'))($scope);`

It basically just let's angular know there is something new it should evaluate and start watching.

(Don't forget to add $compile to your module dependencies).

Further to that I assume you have actually added an object called `fields` on your `$scope`?

Another thing you could do is use ng-change on your form instead of using $watch. The function you bind on ng-change would be invoked every time one of the selects in your form changes.

For further reading have a look at this:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: where exactly do I have to add this .After adding element " myElement.append"

Comment: yeah I think it should work by adding it after `myElement.append('<input type="text" style="width:220px" class="form-control" name="" disabled="" value=' + selected + '> <select class="form-control" style="width:196px" ng-model="fields.privacyStatus" ><option value="range">Range</option><option value="public">Public</option><option value="private">Private</option></select> <br><br>');`

Comment: The above code is assuming your form-control class is unique. So if it is not I suggest you either give it a unique identifier (so we can target it in the compile) or you can compile the element first and then insert it as well.

Comment: Have you initiated `fields` as an object on $scope?

Answer (score 0):

I think that will not work, you are adding only dom, that's all, there's no bind.
One way is to create directive which will do that, or add that input in template with "ng-hidden", and on click just show.